# How do I change dynamically the width and height with an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've created a form, which posses an Input field, that Input field should always have a default value (10px width 10px height). One input field is for the height the secound for the width for the div. I want that if someone changes on of these two values that the div.box react to it. Like if the input is filled with a number 20px width, it should take 20px as width.
This all should happen without a page reload..

How do I archive that?

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="width">Width</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="width" name="width"><br>
  <label for="height">Height</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="height" name="height"><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="box"></div>
```

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/toonytest/pen/poeyywZ

Comment: Plz, share your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: You're probably looking for event listeners to accomplish this. Take a look at this doc and give something a try. Once you try something (even if it doesn't work), post your attempt and we'll give you feedback. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

```js
['width', 'height'].forEach(dimension => {
  window[dimension].addEventListener('change', ({target: { value } }) => {
    box.style[dimension] = value + 'px'
  })
})
```

```css
#box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="width">Width</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="width" name="width" value=10><br>
  <label for="height">Height</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="height" name="height" value=10><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Can I change width with flex-basis? @bel3atar

Comment: @m0n0l0g no you can't

Comment: how can I change input with height and flexbasis?

Comment: @m0n0l0g you can't

Comment: why is this not possible?

Comment: Because flex-basis specifies the initial length of a flexible item. 1) Your item is not a flex item. 2) It only sets the initial width, so it might not display exactly as you want.
Width and height are the way to go here.